# Excel - Drop down list that allows non-listed values

Tags: data-validation, dropdownlist

I'm looking for a way to have a drop-down list based on existing data BUT that allows me to enter values that are not included.

Let me picture the situation:
I have an evaluation form where we enter observations for each different aspects we evaluate, for instance: ´'Customer communication' where if failed we enter the reason, once the evaluation is finished it pastes the information in another tab which is basically a DB of all data of the analyzed incident, including the observations. I found that many times we need to repeat the observations, so I thought it would ease it for us if we had a drop-down menu of the column of that indicator observations but we also need to be able to enter a new comment that would eventually be added to the column. If the data validation = list would allow us to write a new value not included in the list it would do exactly what I need. Is there a work around? I don't see an option to allow a value not included in the list.

Comment: Is this dropdown an html select tag?

Comment: It's excel, regular drop down menu from data validation